# Firestore Rules - Allow "manager" to read/update data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We have 2 roles: manager and user in the system and want to allow manager to read and write data for the user.
We have a collection for each user where we keep to whom that user is reporting. For example:
collection: users/GUIDforTheUser/
In this collection, we keep who reports to whom (AccountId represents the mangager of the userId).

We also have a data collection: data/GUIDforTheUser/, and I want to allow manager(report) to read and write the data to the user who reports to him. How would I write the rule?
[image: users/GUIDforTheUser/]
[image: data/GUIDforTheUser/]

Comment: Can you share screenshots of your document? Like it might be easier to understand "we keep who reports to whom" part then.

Comment: This scenario is pretty close to what is covered in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access I recommend starting with that and reporting back if you run into problems.

Comment: @Dharmaraj, please see below: https://ibb.co/xg4C3xM . AccountId = reportTo

Comment: @D0uble7 the image doesn't load, please update your question with image. Also AccountId field is ID of their manager?>

Comment: @Dharmaraj, updated all of the details. AccountId field is Id of their manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) to fetch `/user/{userId}` document and check if `accountId` in that document matches UID of user trying to read the information:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
    match /data/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data.accountId;
    }   
  }
}
```